# Why can't I add an image using kivy in the main.py?

Tags: python, image, kivy

Code:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_cloud()

    def add_cloud(self):
        img = Image(source="images/cloudbig.png")
        return img

class TestApp(App):
    pass

TestApp().run()
```

What should happen is open the app using the Kivy library, add a widget, then an add an image. Though the image isn't showing up in the window, I just get an empty window.

I tried adding the image using a separate .kv file which worked but I need to have adding the image in a function in the .py file to loop the function.

How could I fix the image not showing on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reasons to this problem of yours are:**

- you can't add the widget(the `Image` widget, in your case specifically) just by returning the object from a method/function, but by using the `self.add_widget` method
- you didn't create any `build` method inside your `TestApp` class, which is essentially required if you don't use the kivy design language

**And here's your code example, fixed:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_cloud()

    def add_cloud(self):
        img = Image(source="images/cloudbig.png")
        self.add_widget(img)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        xd = MainWidget()
        return xd

TestApp().run()
```